# Using pipe during gulp watch

Tags: javascript, gulp

Currently i'm using `gulp watch` to automatically compile my files on update; but now i'm looking to `pipe()` them to multiple other folders.

For example; on use of the gulp command; these commands run:

```
gulp.src(['public/js/*']).pipe(gulp.dest('www'));
gulp.src(['public/css/*']).pipe(gulp.dest('www'));
gulp.src(['public/js/*']).pipe(gulp.dest('platforms/browser/www'));
gulp.src(['public/css/*']).pipe(gulp.dest('platforms/browser/www'));
```

How do I run a `pipe()` task when `gulp watch` notices a file change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [floatdrop/gulp-watch](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch/blob/master/docs/readme.md):

```
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
watch('public/js/*', function () {
    gulp.src('public/js/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('www'));
});
```